# Java getting url with the correct encoding

Tags: java, file, url, encoding, utf-8

I'd like to download the sources of many webpages, then write to the file and print it out in the NetBeans console. I have a problem with encoding. First check my code out:

```
public static final void foo(URL url, Charset endoding, String file) {
    BufferedReader in;
    String readLine;
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), encoding));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(file) , encoding));
        while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(readLine+"\n");
            out.write(readLine+"\n");
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I am testing this on 2 foreign websites (ex. Czech and Thai)

I tried Charset.forName("UTF-8") that seems to work correctly for the Thai webpage but actually for the Czech one doesn't. Console and file contains the question mark such as �.

I have also tried ISO-8859-2, that saves the file correctly, but the console shows small rectangle instead of letters **ž, š** etc..

Does exist any universal solution for multilanguage websites (as Czech, Japan, Thai and more..), that I can save to file correctly as same as print to console or save to variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no such thing as the ultimate encoding. The state of the art encoding would probably be UTF-8 at the time, even though each side can decide which encoding it is using by its own.
[Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a pretty decent article worth of reading that describes the basic problem of char encoding as a world wide solution.

Therefore, the best Solution would be to get the html page encoding with [`InputStreamReader.getEncoding()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#getEncoding()):

```
public static final void foo(URL url, String file){
  BufferedReader in;
  String readLine;
  try{
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    String encoding = isr.getEncoding(); //if you actually need it, which I don't suppose
    in = new BufferedReader(isr);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream(file) , encoding));
    while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(readLine+"\n");
      out.write(readLine+"\n");
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

This should work as intended.

Comment: Hmh ok then I don't really know what to do. Can you give me your website Urlacher where it failed?